# Vary motion speed of a rigged character

Tags: animation, rigging

I am a newbie in the field of 3d-character. Recently I saw a video how to create a rigging character on Maximo website. I download a rigged model and import to blender. So far everything fine.
I was think I can manipulate the animation of this character, just like what I usually do for manipulating an object, for example, a camera. Normally I could change xyz-translation/rotation, speed, rotation…etc. in graph-editor.

However, I just couldn’t modify the animation speed of this character.
What I want is making dancing speed vary, e.g. sometime normal and sometime in slow motion…
I tried to ‚scale up’ all keys in x direction (meaning slower I guess…) in time-line, graph-editor, and dope sheet. Unfortunately, it just doesn’t work. The speed of animation is still the same.

What I found is non-linear animation, where I simply scale up the whole animation (makes slower)
It works, but it only allows me to scale it down or up of the ENTIRE scene. Nothings else.
I can’t access the animation keys to make the speed vary or manipulate for certain keys and change attributes.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're scaling up the right keys?  Find the armature, enter pose mode on it, select all bones (incl. possibly unhiding, and displaying all bone layers), and then look at all the keys in your graph editor.  The keys are not on the armature *object* nor on the mesh object.  Scaling up all *bone* keys in X should do what you want (but that won't necessarily lead to a great looking animation.)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you're editing a copy of an Action, rather than the Action itself.  (Actions are animation segments that you create in the non-linear animation (NLA) editor.  Please add your blend file to your question. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: yesssss! I was so stupid. how can I edit it in object-mode! Thx, it works, when I switch to pose-mode, thx you very much!